# Android not seeing my xml files in anim folder?

Tags: android, xml

In my android project I made an `anim` folder in the `res` folder, and added two xml files. Then I did a clean project command. But when I try to use the xml files, it says it cannot be resolved....

I added these two files

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/slide_in_right.xml

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/slide_out_left.xml

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Be sure that you are using the correct R.anim which is the anim folder of your project.  It might not be finding it if you don't supply the project.package.R.anim folder.

Comment: How do I check? I just right click the res folder and created an anim folder...

Comment: The import at the top should be an indication.  Typically if using Eclipse I would remove the current R import, put my cursor over it and see the suggestions. One of which would request an import option for the R in your package.  But you can figure it out by importing manually with your package name followed by .R if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code I am assuming you are using the animations to change the transitions between activities.

To do this you need to reference it using:

```
R.anim.slide_in_right
```

Furthermore, if you are using it to override transition, youll need the following command where you call your startActivity method:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

I hope this helps